# How to work with GeoSMS?

Tags: android, geosms

I'm looking for any libraries to work with GeoSMS standard on Android.
In the standard says that geosms is just:

```
geo:lat,lon[,alt][;u=accuracy],
```

So maybe everyone work with it without any libs?

Comment: GeoSMS seems like it has been untouched for 18 months - you might have to write your own here a starting point: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: @Mapperz: Yeah its nice. But i can find standart locaion string. Here some info http://geosms.wordpress.com/ but not enough.